# Simultaneous equations in polar coordinates

Tags: systems-of-equations, polar-coordinates

I want to find the intersections of pairs of curves in polar coodinates.
As an example, I have three circles with different offsets in a plane which you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CCwk.png).

The offsets are: $\exp\left({\frac{ i 2\pi}{3}}\right) |  i \in \{0,1,2\} $

which makes the equation for the curves

$\{x,y\}=\{\cos(\theta)+\ \Re(\exp\left(\frac{ i 2\pi n}{3}\right)),\sin(\theta)+\ \Im(\exp\left(\frac{ i 2\pi n}{3}\right))\}$

Now, pairing the curves together and solving for $\theta$ does not give me an answer which I believe is because the angle offset is not the same in the different curves. I believe I should replace $\theta$ in one with $\theta+n \pi$ and solve for n and $\pi$ but I am not getting the correct answers. 
What is the systematic way of doing this?

update:

The parametric equations are:

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 l_1 \\
 l_2 \\
 l_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \sin (u)+1 & \cos (u) \\
 \sin (u)-\frac{1}{2} & \cos (u)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
 \sin (u)-\frac{1}{2} & \cos (u)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Pairing the first two, I have:

$sin (u)+1 =sin (u+2n\pi)-\frac{1}{2}$

$\cos (u) = \cos (u+2n\pi)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $

but $sin (u+2n\pi)=sin(u)$

so for the first equation, we have:

$sin (u)+1 =sin (u)-\frac{1}{2}$

which does not have any answers?

update2: My above approach is wrong. In both cases, when we shift the origin, we are effectively changing both r and theta. Solving for the original theta is meaningless. it is the transformed radius of the two curves that are equal.

Comment: Your approach seems to be fine (except that you should only replace $\theta$ by $\theta+2\pi n$). Can you please explain what results you get? That way we could show you what errors you perhaps made. And note that the intersections are not equal to your 'offsets'/circle midpoints. (The intersections have arguments of $\theta = 2\pi n/3 + \pi/6$ for $n=0,1,2$)

Comment: I don't see how the intersection could possibly be on the circle midpoints! :) we are looking for points on the circles, not in their centers. Thanks, I will update the question to show what I tried.

Comment: @flawr added it now.

Comment: now that I think about it, it can't be 2npi as that will have similar sin and cos value. The only way to get something out of this equations, is to have odd npi. I can't really justify it geometrically though.

Comment: Note that for a given $\phi$ the simultaneous equations $\sin(\phi) = \sin(\theta)$ AND $\cos(\phi) = \cos(\theta)$ imply that $\theta = \phi + 2\pi n$ for a certain $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with polar coordinates. You are given two curves through parametrical representations:
$$\eqalign{&\gamma_1:\quad u\mapsto\bigl(x_1(u),y_1(u)\bigr)\quad (a\leq u\leq b),\cr
&\gamma_2:\quad v\mapsto\bigl(x_2(v),y_2(v)\bigr)\quad (c\leq v\leq d),\cr}\tag{1}$$
and you want to find their points of intersection. Such a point is generated whenever there is a "time" $u$ for the first curve, and a "time" $v$ for the second such that $\gamma_1(u)=\gamma_2(v)$. Therefore we find these points by solving the system
$$x_1(u)=x_2(v),\quad y_1(u)=y_2(v)$$
for $u$ and $v$ and plugging the obtained values into $(1)$.

In the simple example of your figure there are of course geometric considerations that lead to the points of intersection with much less work.

Comment: Thanks. I got it mixed up and was just confusing myself! :)